# show block toolbar programmatically gutenberg

Tags: block, toolbar, wordpress-gutenberg

I am creating a block with InnerBlocks component.
If no content added to the InnerBlocks (and even with content in fact) it is very difficult to popup the block toolbar
I would like to add an iconbutton on top corner that will show the block floating toolbar
How can I tell the .block-editor-block-contextual-toolbar to show?
I don't see any method of the .wp-block in the inspector that would do that and the documentation of Block Controls: Block Toolbar and Settings Sidebar https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/block-controls-toolbar-and-sidebar/ is quite basic
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useSelect()` to determine if there are any blocks present in the `InnerBlocks` component:

```js
import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';

const hasInnerBlocks = useSelect((select) => (
    select('core/block-editor').getBlock(clientId).innerBlocks.length > 0
), [clientId]);
```

Then you can use `hasInnerBlocks` to conditionally render whatever you'd like within the `edit` function:

```js
{ !!hasInnerBlocks && (
    <BlockControls group="block">
        <ToolbarGroup
            // Toolbar group settings here
        />
    </BlockControls>

) }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer! I will try that! How do you find that documentation?

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted to know.
What I need it to show the blockcontrols when I click on the block.
My block with innerblocks is not showing it when I click on it
I need to show that:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WordPress/gutenberg/HEAD/docs/assets/toolbar-text.png

Comment: It sounds like you have the _child_ block selected. `BlockControls` are contextual, based on which block you have selected. This includes `InnerBlocks`. If you select the parent block, it should show the `BlockControls`.

Comment: Yes but when I click on the parent block it is not showing the blockcontrols. Il will add my code to github and share it here...

Comment: Here is my code: https://github.com/GregoireSailland/un-block-collection

Comment: You haven't actually used `BlockControls` in your [`edit` function](https://github.com/GregoireSailland/un-block-collection/blob/main/src/blocks/background-wrapper/edit.js#L59-L82). Here is [an example in one of my blocks that actually uses `BlockControls`](https://github.com/philbuchanan/Accordion-Blocks/blob/master/src/block/edit.js#L147-L191).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will add the background selector and other settings in this blockControls.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use same code structure among the edit and save methods. The RIchText need to be waraped inside div.

```
<div>
<RichText.Content
 className={ `sticky-note-${ props.attributes.alignment }` }
 style={ {
     fontSize: props.attributes.fontSize,backgroundColor: props.attributes.color,
  } }
  tagName="p"
  value={ props.attributes.content }/>
</div>
```

Comment: Though I did not see your code . But this ca be the situations. In my case this was the problem

Answer (score 0):

#### Example

I created this example to illustrate your situation.

```js
import { InnerBlocks, BlockControls } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

// ...

edit: () => {
    const blockProps = {
        // your own props
    };

    return (
        <div { ...blockProps }>
            <BlockControls>
                // your controls
            </BlockControls>
            <InnerBlocks />
        </div>
    );
}
```

---

#### Problem

For the `BlockControls` to decide whether or not it should appear, it needs to get some **context from its parent** which your own props don't have.

---

#### Solution:

**Use the block props** instead for the parent of `BlockControls`.

---

#### Steps:

1. Import `useBlockProps` from `@wordpress/block-editor`:

```js
import { InnerBlocks, BlockControls, useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
```

2. Pass your own props as an argument to `useBlockProps()`:

```js
const blockProps = useBlockProps({
    // your own props
});
```

---

### Result

```js
import { InnerBlocks, BlockControls, useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

// ...

edit: () => {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps({
        // your own props
    });

    return (
        <div { ...blockProps }>
            <BlockControls>
                // your controls
            </BlockControls>
            <InnerBlocks />
        </div>
    );
}
```

---

### Links

I hope that helped.

My answer is based on Wordpress's official Block Editor Handbook:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/block-controls-toolbar-and-sidebar/#block-toolbar
- https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/nested-blocks-inner-blocks/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-edit-save/#block-wrapper-props